# Create color legend in scatter plot python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to work with the following code:

```
color= ['red' if House =="20" "blue" elif House =="21" "yellow" elif House =="22" else 'green' for H in House]
```

It gives the following error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any suggestion-Idea?

Comment: What kind of syntax is this? Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` can't be used in list comprehension. It should be `else <value> if <condition>`. Applying to your code:

```
color= ['red' if H=="20" else "blue" if H =="21" else "yellow" if H =="22" else 'green' for H in House]
```

Note you are iterating over `H`, not over `House`

**update:**

The general syntax look like:

```
[<value> if <condition> else <value> if <condition> else <value>]
```

This can be split into three parts:

1. `<value> if <condition>`

   This corresponds to `if <condition>: <value>`
2. `else <value> if <condition>`

   This corresponds to `elif <condition>: <value>`
3. `else <value>`

   This corresponds to `else: <value>`

Comment: as you mention **else <value> if <condition>** up there but what you have done is   **<value>if <condition> else <value>**

Comment: @AyemunHossainAshik Before you can use an `elif` statement, you of course need an `if` statement. I've updated to answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I am talking about the line above you code . Correct that .

Comment: @AyemunHossainAshik I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. The line above the code says that if you want to use `elif` in list comprehension it should be written as `else <value> if <condition>`. It is also like this is in the code as explained more in the update.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to read if you use a dictionary:

```
colour_map = {
    '20': 'red',
    '21': 'blue',
    '22': 'yellow',
}

color= ['green' if H not in colour_map.keys() else colour_map[H] for H in House]
```